# Bin a column grouped by the values of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a new column with the binned values grouped by another column. A sample data set with the bins by year would like something like this:

```
Year    A   Bin
1999    1   [1-3]
1999    3   [1-3]
1999    10  [10-11]
1999    11  [10-11]
2000    43  [39-43]
2000    39  [39-43]
2000    22  [20-23]
2000    21  [20-23]
2001    11  [10-11]
2001    10  [10-11]
2001    198 [185-200]
2001    188 [185-200]
```

I've used `pd.cut` but I'm having trouble getting it to bin within each year and not for the entire column. 
I tried using this function but I'm getting an error: `TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable`.

```
def var_to_bins(dataset, var, num_bins):
    dataset[str(var)+'_test'] = dataset.groupby(dataset.survyear(pd.cut(dataset[var], num_bins)))
```

Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: My expected output is the Bin column. Perhaps I wasn't clear. For example using the data above, I want `A` divided into two bins for each year but currently I'm only able to divide `A` into two bins for the entire columns. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I modify answer, but still not 100% sure if this is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need:

```
dataset['Bins'] = dataset.groupby('Year')['A'].transform(lambda x: pd.cut(x, 2))
print (dataset)
    Year    A        Bin            Bins
0   1999    1      [1-3]     (0.99, 6.0]
1   1999    3      [1-3]     (0.99, 6.0]
2   1999   10    [10-11]     (6.0, 11.0]
3   1999   11    [10-11]     (6.0, 11.0]
4   2000   43    [39-43]    (32.0, 43.0]
5   2000   39    [39-43]    (32.0, 43.0]
6   2000   22    [20-23]  (20.978, 32.0]
7   2000   21    [20-23]  (20.978, 32.0]
8   2001   11    [10-11]  (9.812, 104.0]
9   2001   10    [10-11]  (9.812, 104.0]
10  2001  198  [185-200]  (104.0, 198.0]
11  2001  188  [185-200]  (104.0, 198.0]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!